# Windows 7 began freezing hanging due to Kaspersky 2014

Tags: windows-7, freeze, kaspersky

2014-Aug-02: Over the last few weeks, two separate Windows 7 systems started freezing / hanging, after 30 seconds to 1 minute after rebooting. If I hesitated after rebooting, I would not be able to log in -- in fact, the user accounts icons would all disappear from the screen. If I didn't hesitate and logged in immediately after rebooting, after 30 seconds to 1 minute, the system would freeze / hang. To clarify "freeze / hang", the mouse was still responding to movement but I was unable to click the Start Orb or any other item on the desktop. If I previously had a window open, I could move it but not close or interact with it in any other way.

Since these systems were previously working without issue for many consecutive months, I presume it to be due to a recent Windows Update and/or Kaspersky Antivirus issue.

Comment: A very detailed question, but essentially a shopping recommendation question which is generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: See [what topics are welcome here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). In my humble opinion this looks like being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: By following [Microsoft's recommended approach to Run Selective Startup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-selective-startup-system-configuration#1TC=windows-7) and, through a process of elimination, discovered **the ROOT CAUSE to be Kaspersky (KIS) 2014**. Once I removed it from my computers, the issues went away and the system resumed working 100% to expectations.

In regard to Kaspersky's "support" team, English is not their primary language (based in Russia) and, as a result, the majority of technical questions result in either (1) a bland, generic "cookie cutter" response, (2) a complete misunderstanding of the issue being reported, (3) run-around proposed resolutions which avoid addressing the core issue being reported.  Worse yet, their support team will CLOSE support cases, even though the user has provided irrefutable proof (screenshots, etc) of the issue occurring.

Aside from the aforementioned disaster which I discovered today, here's what they missed:

- The product hangs / shows a grey icon in taskbar, when coming out of Hibernation on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 systems.
- While Full Scan was running, I paused KIS2014 Protection and could NOT enable it until I first manually stopped the Full Scan.
- When the aforementioned occurs, right-clicking the taskbar icon often results in the app immediately terminating thereby leaving the computer complete unprotected.
- The product offers NO technical logging. Moreover, what little logs are shown are presented in a GUI format intended for novice users.
- The Parental Controls feature is extremely limited, in that it fails to offer exceptions. Either downloads are allowed or they are not - no specific exceptions, for example.
- The app includes a "Root Kit" scan with several issues: (1) it cannot be scheduled; it either runs at logon or it never runs, (2) a true root kit scan would not take place on an active system; hence, the true definition of a root kit is one that alters (at a low-level) what is being hidden and/or reported to the OS.